# Problema de filtro de intents en app poniendo android:exported

Tags: android, android-manifest

Estoy intentando subir mi .aab a playstore de mi aplicacion en flutter. Tengo un error al subirla que es el siguiente:

Has subido un APK o Android App Bundle que tiene una actividad, un alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported. Este archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores. Consulta developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Estoy agregando en el activity tag del android manifest el android:exported="true" y sigue tirando el mismo error

Dejo mi AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="ar.com.questioncolor">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"  />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
<!-- The Agora SDK requires Bluetooth permissions in case users are using Bluetooth devices.-->
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"  />

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Question Professional"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:label">

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
            />
    </provider>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDQqBXDAppv4Aq3-3HLVpXqVy12q3Bgceg" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

</application>
```

Comment: tengo el mismo problema por ahora, sospecho que tiene que ver con las versiones de sdk. Sin embargo es necesario investigar mas a fondo si se trata de alguna configuración del build.gradle

Comment: Alguien pudo resolver este problema?, aun cambiando android:exported="true" sigue mostrando el mismo error Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar:
android:exported="true"
en cada activity que tengas con un intent-filter dentro.
Por ejemplo:

```
<activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTop"
       android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
       android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Es decir que si tienes más de un "activity" con un "intent-filter" debes poner la propiedad "exported" en true a cada uno. Yo tuve el mismo problema en la última actualización de mi app y de esta forma me funcionó.